# DELETE from same table used in the WHERE

Tags: mariadb

I have the following query that is supposed to delete from a table with a circular FK requirement;

```
DELETE FROM question 
WHERE defaultGotoQuestionId IN (
    SELECT id from question WHERE facilityId IN (
        SELECT id FROM facility WHERE customerId NOT IN (1,76)
        )
    );
```

But I get the following error;

*Table is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data*

I understand the error message - that I can't DELETE from a TABLE that I am specifying in the WHERE - I just can't seem to work out how to solve it, for myself.
I saw a few examples of using a join - but perhaps I am having an off day - because I have been iterating through copy/paste examples - but still can't manage it.

It works as a SELECT : In that the result gives me the records I want to delete;

```
SELECT id FROM question 
WHERE defaultGotoQuestionId IN (
    SELECT id from question WHERE facilityId IN (
        SELECT id FROM facility WHERE customerId NOT IN (1,76)
        )
    );
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of MariaDB are you using?

> [DELETE :: Same Source and Target Table](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/delete/#same-source-and-target-table)
>
> Until MariaDB 10.3.1, deleting from a table with the same source and target was not possible. From MariaDB 10.3.1, this is now possible.

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=a8cd28c00c3cf4ad330ad561cfdc9a58).

In older versions of MariaDB (or in MySQL, for example), one option you can use is:

```sql
DELETE
  `question`
FROM
  `question`
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      `id`
    FROM
      `question`
    WHERE  
      `defaultGotoQuestionId` IN (
        SELECT
          `id`
        FROM
          `question`
        WHERE
          `facilityId` IN (
            SELECT
              `id`
            FROM
              `facility`
            WHERE
              `customerId` NOT IN (1, 5)
          )
      )
  ) `der` ON
    `question`.`id` = `der`.`id`;
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=513392b13d464026d86e1b068053d3cb).

Comment: Thanks for the work you did on this - it really helped me out!